# inequalities and limits

Tags: inequality

I have a question about inequalities and limits.

I'm given a joint pdf, where I have to find the marginal distributions of the two random variables respectively. The given inequality is $0<x_1<x_2 <1$. So if I want to find the marginal density of $x_2$, then I will integrate over the limits $0<x_1<x_2 $ and if I want to find the marginal density of $x_1$, then I will integrate over the interval $x_1 <x_2 <1$.
I know how to come from a joint pdf to a marginal density with the limits.

My question is though, when I have my marginal density, say fx $f(x_1)=4x_1$, then why are the limits of $x_1$ then $0<x_1<1$ and not $0<x_1<x_2$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the density function is regular enough, marginal density function is $$\rho_{X_1}(x_1) = \int_\mathbb{R}\rho_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) dx_2 $$

The condition $0<x_1<x_2<1$ means that the integrand in the formula above is $0$ except on a segment $[x_1,1]$.

The space defined as $0<x_1<1, 0<x_2<x_1$ is the same as the space defined as  $0<x_2<1, x_2<x_1<1$. So, if you change the order of integration: $$ 1 = \int_0^1 dx_1 \underbrace{\int_0^{x_1} dx_2 f(x_1, x_2)}_{\text{marginal distribution}f_{X_1}(x_1)} = \int_0^1 dx_2 \underbrace{\int_{x_1}^1 dx_1 f(x_1, x_2)}_{\text{marginal distribution}f_{X_2}(x_2)}$$

I am not sure if this answers your question. If it does not, could you rephrase it in terms of formulae?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but after you have found the marginal density for $x_1$, how can the interval become $0<x_1 <1$, - I got it from the solution behind the book. I cannot understand, how we can go from $0<x_1 <x_2$ to $0<x_1 <1$ for the same variable?

Comment: The space defined as $0<x_1<1, 0<x_2<x_1$ is the same as the space defined as  $0<x_2<1, x_2<x_1<1$. If you think in terms of integration, it is as if you change the order of integration: $\int_0^1 dx_1 \int_0^{x_1} dx_2 f(x_1, x_2) = \int_0^1 dx_2 \int_{x_1}^1 dx_1 f(x_1, x_2)$